# Append to pq.StringArray in Golang

Tags: arrays, go, append, goland

I have the following code:

```
users = append(users, user)
```

where users is a pg.StringArray. Goland IDE complains that this statement is invalid because of the following reason:

Cannot use 'users' (type pq.StringArray) as the type []Type

Is there a way to append to pq.StringArray in Go? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `users` is of type `pq.StringArray` and `user` is of type `string` then `append(users, user)` is ok. If your IDE complains then your IDE is mistaken. (unless you've redeclared `append` as your own function with an incompatible signature which is not smart)

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming that. And how do I check if users is empty or not? Comparing to nil is not possible.

Comment: `if len(users) == 0 { println("no users") }`. Note `len` returns `0` for both `nil` slices and non-`nil` but empty slices. https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.19.2#len

Comment: The len function is not applicable to pq.StringArray.

Comment: It is applicable, see: https://go.dev/play/p/kKTptZtIA1a. If, however, by `pq.StringArray` you do NOT mean `StringArray` from `github.com/lib/pq`, then you MAY be right. But, the commonly used, `github.com/lib/pq`'s `StringArray` is just a *named* slice of strings (i.e. `[]string`). It is a slice type and it functions as any other slice type.

Comment: Please understand that IDEs are complex environments and they are very easy to misconfigure. So if your IDE is complaining about some code that is obviously correct, you should first double-check by compiling the code outside of the IDE with just the official `go` tool. If that fails as well then the problem is with the code, but if it passes then your IDE is misconfigured, or just plain buggy.

Comment: Can you share a full code snippet and upload it to Go Playground?

Comment: Thank you for all your help. The issue has now been resolved.